# Name of the sample music that comes with Ubuntu

Tags: sound, music

What is the name of the sample music that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? It is a guitar song with a female vocal.

Comment: i guess it was ver 18LTS or 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song featured in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is called "I don't know" ([YouTube link to the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pc0QZRM_dbI)), the artist is Jenyfa Duncan ([SoundCloud profile](https://soundcloud.com/jenyfa-duncan)).

Another song called "Australia" ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdE9uWRRhrc)) by the same artist was featured before in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I made this search looking for another music that is not listed by @pomsky. But I find it in this another answer [Built-in demo / example song Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410755/built-in-demo-example-song-ubuntu) and the name is Swansong - Josh Woodward.