# Built-in demo / example song Ubuntu

Tags: music

I have a question.
In the past, when I was a child, I used Ubuntu as an alternative for Windows XP. You should think of 2010-2014.
In the example songs folder, there has been a demo song that got stuck in my mind.

Nowadays I try to find this song, but unfortunately I cannot find it.

The chorus of the song is like: "oh oh, I don't know, I ....", along with nice piano music. And it was always in the example folder.

Does anybody have a clue of the artist and title of the song?

Thank you for thinking with me :)

Kind regards,

Joey from the Netherlands

Comment: I've used Ubuntu since years before your alluded time period and have no memory of any demo song being bundled with Ubuntu.

Comment: But apparently there is: [Name of the sample music that comes with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200273/name-of-the-sample-music-that-comes-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you, ChanganAuto. However, those are not the song I mean. I am 100% sure the song was bundled in an "Examples" folder in my Home folder.

Answer (score 3):

After watching a lot of YouTube videos, and letting my brain work, I finally found the built in song:

Swansong - Josh Woodward

It was featured in at least Ubuntu 12.04.

Problem solved